# Make errors recoverable with Spring JPA application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, error-handling

I have a simple Spring JPA application that initializes in the following way:

Main.Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        try {           
            
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
                
        
        }
        
        catch(Exception ex) {
            
         System.out.println("This is my exception handler");
         ...Real exception handling here...
        }           
    }
}
```

Sample class:

```
@Component
public class SampleClass extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    TablaUsuariosInterface userRepo;
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleClass .class);

    public String validar(Plantilla plantilla) {
    
        try {

...code for the JPA operations
}
catch(Exception ex) {

System..out.println("It's dead Jim")
..Real exception handling here...
}
}
```

When I cause an intentional error (for example, disconnecting the Database) I get the expected message :

> This is my exception handler

or

> It's dead Jim

Very good. The problem is, I also get a huge stack trace with dozens of lines, and a total application crash. I'll put the more relevant lines here:

> 2021-08-18 15:26:03.564 ERROR 11112 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
> during pool initialization.
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
> ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>
> at webservices.Main.main(Main.java:17) ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link
> failure
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate
> protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
> DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

I understand that everything stated on the stack trace is true.

But since I already have my error handling, how can I get rid of that unnecessary stack trace without changing the log level?

EDIT 2:

The application will be running on a web server, the end-user will have no means of restarting it after an error. Currently, the only means of recovering from an error is restarting the application.

EDIT 1:

Tried adding the following code instead of my usual try{} catch{}

```
public class Main extends RuntimeException {

}

@ExceptionHandler(Main.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e) {
        implemented code to log & handle exception.
    }
```

But spring also ignores it.

Comment: You were going to get the startup abort (not really a crash) anyway. Why do you consider the stack trace unnecessary, since you need to know why you had a problem?

Comment: Because the problem doesn't always occur at startup: let's say you suddenly lose database connectivity after the application is up and running. Currently, the application throws an error and closes. I would like to simply interrupt the request, return a proper response to the end-user and make the error recoverable (i.e.) try to send the request again when connectivity is resored, without restarting the application.

Comment: It is not all ordinary behavior for an entire Spring application to "close" if it receives an error from the database; instead, individual requests produce error responses, and database errors aren't propagated to the top level like you illustrated. Something else is going on here, and it sounds like you don't have a standard Spring Boot MVC application configured.